# Descargar un gran volumen de datos desde Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, couchbase

Estoy haciendo pruebas con [`Firebase`](https://firebase.google.com/?hl=es-419) en `Android` y me gustaría usarla en un proyecto en el que una app tiene que descargar datos maestros antes de que el usuario pueda trabajar con la app.

Un ejemplo, sería si imaginamos una aplicación con soporte offline para diseñar coches, antes de poder diseñar un coche la aplicación debe descargar los datos maestros de diseño de vehículos:

> motores, ruedas, volantes, puertas, colores, asientos...

Todos estos datos maestros suponen un volumen importante de transferencia.

Mi pregunta es:
¿Conocéis alguna forma de descargar todos estos datos con `FireBase`, mostrando al usuario el típico `ProgressDialog`? Algo como lo que se hace con  [Replication en CouchBase](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html)

Comment: Haces una llamada asíncrona... y mientras no acabe pones un loader xD

Comment: Ten en cuenta que ProcessDialog ya esta deprecado, tendrás que usar otra alternativa... Pero sí, con un AsyncTask lo tienes. Busca alguna librería especifica para Firebase que seguro que ya existe.

Comment: supongo que el método que debo poner un AsyncTask es  este FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

Comment: En este video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c93iGKyvh3o en el minuto 3:41 hacen una pregunta similar "For mobile, is there any way to prepopulate the cache so the initial sync with the server is minimal? Dev eats up bandwidth. Thx" te podría orientar la respuesta